# What is the significance of a Naruto hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

I received a "Naruto" hat / badge today on StackOverflow. Apparently it is for "posting an accepted answer that receives no other votes for 12 hours".

I don't understand what is the significance of this achievement or why it ties into "Naruto", whom I understand is an anime superhero character or something. Can someone explain?

Comment: Related: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/1176

Comment: Wikipedia: "an adolescent ninja who constantly searches for recognition and dreams to become the Hokage, the ninja in his village who is acknowledged as the leader and the strongest of all."  With the extrapolation that watching 12 hours of manga feels like forever.

Answer (score 5):

> I don't understand what is the significance of this achievement

It's related to who Naruto is.

> or why it ties into "Naruto", whom I understand is an anime superhero character or something. Can someone explain?

If you know about the topic is pretty simple (through IMO, SE skewed with the order). Naruto wasn't accepted and/or recognized from early on. In this case it means that your answer was helpful for the OP but not for the rest of the community in the first 12 hours of life (which is pretty much the most critical time you can hope to get upvotes).